# DataTables JSON Api escape content

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I got some data that I'm pulling from JSON API endpoint, one of the data records has object property called requestor. Here is what I mean :

```
data looks like so -> [{requestor: "First Lastname <email@email.com>", some_other: 'prop'}, {requestor: "Lastname first <email2@email.com>", some_other: 'prop'}...{requestor n}]
```

The problem with this is that when it renders the table column content it renders it like so :

[image]

As a result only `First Lastname` shows up for the column content on the screen.

Is there a way 
I can 'escape' these `<` `>` or do something so this is treated like a text and not like HTML tag?

Datatables does offer render function callback, where I can return anything, but what do I return for this to be treated like a text?

**Update per first edit below:**

I can't want to replace `<` and `>` I need to print this into the table column `First Lastname <email@email.com>`

Answer (score 1):

A simple regex in render worked for me. Here is the code:

```
$('#dtable').DataTable({
    data: [{requestor: "First Lastname <email@email.com>", some_other: 'prop'}, {requestor: "Lastname first <email2@email.com>", some_other: 'prop'}],
    columns: [
      {
        data: 'requestor',
        render: data => data.replace(/[<]/g, '&lt;').replace(/[>]/g, '&gt;')
      },
      {data: 'some_other'}
    ],
})
```

Comment: hi @Rahul Pal I want to render `First Lastname <email@email.com>` I don't want to replace the `<>`, how can I do that?

Comment: @Echotest You can also use  `render: $.fn.dataTable.render.text()`